# Windows XP Mouse button stuck -- Software issue

Tags: windows-xp, mouse

I have a strange issue.  A Windows XP machine had a virus.  The machine was then re-imaged to a previous point in time.  Then all of the Windows Updates were applied.  Now, at about the same time of day everyday, the left mouse button input appears to be stuck down.  When moving the mouse across the desktop a box appears as if you are holding down the left mouse button.  Actually clicking the left mouse button causes the context menu to appear, as if the right mouse button was clicked.  This issue disappears after a reboot.

Any suggestions as to what might be causing this issue?

Comment: By 're-imaged' do you mean actually re-imaged or are you talking about rolling windows back to a restore point? If its the restore point you could easily still have a virus.

Comment: I mean re-imaged.  After setting up the PC initially two years ago a Symantec Ghost 11.0 image was created.  This image was then re applied to the machine.